# SATA hard drive has extremely slow write speed

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

[image: A dead dawg. A DEAD DAWG I SAY!]

It was fine until one morning, a few days ago.

Any ideas? Can it be fixed?

P.S. completing that benchmark took FOREVER

Comment: Have you checked the SMART data to see if the drive can see anything wrong itself? Also, have you been in the case recently, because a bad or loose SATA cable could cause issues like this as well.

Comment: This hard-drive doesn't have any pre-installed software similar to SMART. However, I did unplug and replug the SATA cable this morning, after realizing this issue. I'll check the cable again to be sure.

Comment: No luck. Probably not related to the SATA cable. :(

Comment: To my knowledge, almost all SATA drives use SMART monitoring. For Windows, you need a tool like http://www.hdtune.com/ to view the information. Other than that, standard troubleshooting applies, try another drive, move drive to another PC or external controller, etc.

Comment: I downloaded the free trial version of HDTune, and upon running it I saw this: http://imgur.com/vHqeHyR Surely it must be incorrect? Any thoughts? I've disconnected the hard drive atm.

Comment: Actually, it is probably completely accurate. I would backup the data immediately to another device and replace the drive. You could attempt to wipe the drive and format it again, but there is clearly an issue here and the drive should be assumed to be failing.

Comment: I backed up all the data yesterday, so that's a plus. It's a shame that it's dying, but it served me well. I'm going to try to do a zero-format anyways, and see if that works. Thanks for the assistance @acejavelin

Comment: Have you tried running CrystalDiskInfo to have better idea about the disk?